# How to load CSV file to MySQL using SourceStream?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, stream, bulkinsert

I am trying to load a csv file to mysql database table using a stream. But MySqlBulkLoader is not identifying the property SourceStream. I am little confused about using SourceStream  in MySqlBulkLoader.

```
    List<string> data= File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\mycsv.txt").ToList();

    string myConn = "Server=localhost;Database=AAAA;Uid=BBB;Pwd=CCCC";
    MySqlConnection testConn= new MySqlConnection(myConn );
    var stream = new MemoryStream()
    MySqlBulkLoader bulk = new MySqlBulkLoader(testConn)
    {
      CharacterSet = "UTF8",
      FieldQuotationCharacter = '\t',
      LineTerminator = "\r\n",
      NumberOfLinesToSkip = 1,
      TableName = "mytable",
      Local = false,
      SourceStream = stream 
      var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);   

     foreach (var d in data)
        writer.WriteLine(string.Join("\t", d));     

     writer.Flush();
     stream.Position = 0;

   }

    bulk.Load();
```

The error is:

> MySqlBulkLoader' does not contain a definition for 'SourceStream'

Thanks for your help to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

*You should set `Local=true`, it will fix the issue.*

Related Doc: [MySqlBulkLoader.SourceStream property](https://mysqlconnector.net/api/mysqlconnector/mysqlbulkloader/sourcestream/)

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to load data from S3 bucket to My SQL in just line of code

```
LOAD DATA FROM S3 's3://db-bucket-name/folder-name/test.csv' INTO TABLE table-name FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"+'"'+"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```